# What is the meaning of curly brackets { } in string resource file of android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-jetpack-navigation

In fragments navigation [codelabs](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-fragments-navigation-component?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-kotlin-unit-3-pathway-2%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-training-fragments-navigation-component#9) I found a use of curly braces {} inside a string tag in string.xml

```
<string name="word_list_fragment_label">Words That Start With {letter}</string>
```

On running the app {letter} is replaced with whatever letter button user presses. What does {letter} refer to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{x}` gets replaced with a value `x` from navigation arguments.

This is a "new" feature of androidx-navigation 1.0.0 alpha 08:

> Destination labels, when used with NavigationUI methods, will now automatically replace {argName} instances in your android:label with the correct argument b/80267266

Source: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation (page fragment names duplicated so cannot link directly to that release)

Android issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80267266

Comment: interesting..i deleted my answer

Answer (score -2):

Follow this steps:

step 1: add this string in your XML file

```
<string name="word_list_fragment_label">Words That Start With &#123; %s &#125;</string>
```

step 2: in your activity perform set text like this :

```
yourTextView.text = String.format(getString(R.string.word_list_fragment_label),"Your text that you want to set")
```

Comment: how does this answer the question ?